# Linux - Route Specific Traffic Through Ethernet

Tags: linux, routes

At work we have 2 networks; a WiFi one for normal Internet access, and an internal LAN one, for the repo etc. I've recently started using Linux and it's a pain having to constantly switch between cable and WiFi. On Windows, we solved it (so that we can be connected to both network simultaneously) by running the commands:

```
# Add a route for all traffic to any destination starting with 10 (internal traffic):
route add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 10.18.21.129 metric 40 -p
# Move the default route to a higher metric:
route change 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 10.18.21.129 metric 40
```

After running these and connecting to WiFi, everything worked magically. What would the necessary Linux commands be to achieve the same result? I've fiddled around a lot with the `route` command, but haven't had any luck. Appreciate any help.

EDIT:
Here is the output of the `route -n` command before entering any other commands:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.18.21.129    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.18.21.128    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet0
192.168.88.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variant 1: *Direct translation of your solution to linux one*

route command:

- route add -net 10.0.0.0/8 gw 10.18.21.125 metric 40
- route del default
- route add default gw 10.18.21.125 metric 40

ip route command:

- ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 via 10.18.21.125 metric 40
- ip route del default via 10.18.21.125
- ip route add default via 10.18.21.125 metric 40

add launch of these command after wifi would be connected or to startup script.

Variant 2. *Turn magic off :)*

- turn route of 10.0.0.0 network via your LAN interface using command like this: `ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 via 10.18.21.125 metric 10`.
  In that case all traffic would be routed via default interface, except 10.0.0.0/8 network.
- increase priority for default wifi route, if he is lower than LAN one

PS. Possibly this question should be placed on Server Fault site :)

EDIT: according to provided route map

- route del default
- route add default gw [wifi gateway ip]
- route add -net 10.0.0.0/8 gw 10.18.21.125

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Those commands didn't seem to help. I've added some output from the "route -n" command in the first post, perhaps it will help. Sorry about this, I'm very new to routing.

Comment: try to use EDIT section, possibly it would be help you